# Identify Arduino Version through USB and Processing

Tags: arduino, usb, processing

I have one big problem: I wrote two Processing applications, one for the Arduino Uno and one for the Arduino Mega. Both applications runs simultaneously on one computer with both Arduinos plugged to the usb ports.

My problem is now to identify automatically the right Arduino device on each application. I could select the port manually, but such an approach is not practicable for the user.

Comment: "but such an approach is not practicable for the user"? why? If you have two dedicated, always the same, ports then this would hardly be a chore to connect to?